# How to transform and extract fields in Kafka sink JDBC connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using a 3rd party CDC tool that replicates data from a source database into Kafka topics. An example row is shown below:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "USER_ID":{  
         "string":"1"
      },
      "USER_CATEGORY":{  
         "string":"A"
      }
   },
   "beforeData":{  
      "Data":{  
         "USER_ID":{  
            "string":"1"
         },
         "USER_CATEGORY":{  
            "string":"B"
         }
      }
   },
   "headers":{  
      "operation":"UPDATE",
      "timestamp":"2018-05-03T13:53:43.000"
   }
}
```

What configuration is needed in the sink file in order to extract all the (sub)fields under `data` and `headers` and ignore those under `beforeData` so that the target table in which the data will be transferred by Kafka Sink will contain the following fields:

```
USER_ID, USER_CATEGORY, operation, timestamp
```

I went through the [transformation list in confluent's docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html) but I was not able to find how to use them in order to achieve the aforementioned target.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're willing to list specific field names, you can solve this by:

1. Using a Flatten transform to collapse the nesting (which will convert the original structure's paths into dot-delimited names)
2. Using a Replace transform with `rename` to make the field names be what you want the sink to emit
3. Using another Replace transform with `whitelist` to limit the emitted fields to those you select

For your case it might look like:

```
  "transforms": "t1,t2,t3",
  "transforms.t1.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value",
  "transforms.t2.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
  "transforms.t2.renames": "data.USER_ID:USER_ID,data.USER_CATEGORY:USER_CATEGORY,headers.operation:operation,headers.timestamp:timestamp",
  "transforms.t3.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
  "transforms.t3.whitelist": "USER_ID,USER_CATEGORY,operation,timestamp",
```

Comment: Can we also flatten the ArrayList in JSON data? I'm facing the below issue in my elastic sink connector while flattening the ArrayList. 
**Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Flatten transformation does not support class java.util.ArrayList for record without schemas**

Comment: The above solution is not working when you have any Arraylist on your data. Do you know how to tackle the Arraylist flatten and blacklist/whitelist the Array?

Answer (score 9):

I think you want `ExtractField`, and unfortunately, it's a `Map.get` operation, so that means 1) nested fields cannot be gotten in one pass 2) multiple fields need multiple transforms.

That being said, you might to attempt this (untested)

```
transforms=ExtractData,ExtractHeaders
transforms.ExtractData.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value
transforms.ExtractData.field=data
transforms.ExtractHeaders.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value
transforms.ExtractHeaders.field=headers
```

If that doesn't work, you might be better off implementing your own Transformations package that can at least drop values from the Struct / Map.

Comment: You could take a look at Debezium's `io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope` transform, and modify that to suit your purpose (and then share it with the community as other users of that 3rd party source CDC tool will have the same requirements)

Comment: @cricket_007 Doesn't seem to work. I'm getting a `NullPointerException `when I try to extract two fields.

Comment: Yeah, figured as much. The first field probably extracts fine, but that's the only remaining object, so the second field can't be extracted. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/ExtractField.java

Comment: Maybe try doing two HoistField transforms to some temp Struct, then use ExtractField on that. Otherwise, like I said, you're going to have to write your own, and add it to the classpath