# extract and transform kafka message specific fields for jdbc sink connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, transformation, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a kafka topic which is getting data from mysql database using Debezium mysql source connector, following is the format of one of the messages:

```
{
    "Message": {
        "schema": {
            "type": "struct",
            "fields": [
              ...
            ],
            "optional": true,
            "name": "mysql-server-1.inventory.somename"
        },
        "payload": {
            "op": "u",
            "ts_ms": 1465491411815,
            "before": {
                "id": 1004,
                "first_name": "Anne",
                "last_name": "Doof",
                "email": "annek@noanswer.org"
            },
            "after": {
                "id": 1004,
                "first_name": "Anne",
                "last_name": "Marry",
                "email": "annek@noanswer.org"
            },
            "source": {
                "db": "inventory",
                "table": "customers",
                ...
                "query": "Update customers set last_name = 'Marry' where id = 1004"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to push `ts_ms, before, after` and `id` (from the object/row) columns into another database using jdbc sink connector with table schema as `(id,before(text),after(text),timestamp)`, being new to kafka cant figure out:

- how can i extract these fields only, from the message to push and ignore others?
- how can i transform before, after fields to string/serialize format?
- how can i extract `id` from object? (incase of insert operation, before will be null, for delete, after will be null)

For the message above, the sink destination table should have data like this below at the end:

```
id:     1004
before: '{"id":1004,"first_name":"Anne","last_name":"Doof","email":"annek@noanswer.org"}'
after:  '{"id":1004,"first_name":"Anne","last_name":"Marry","email":"annek@noanswer.org"}'
timestamp: 1465491411815
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use chain of [Kafka Connect Transformations](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html), like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56601093/7109598).

Comment: thanks @Iskuskov Alexander, can you devise something concrete that can work for both requirements, transforming AND Json serialization?

Comment: Do you need `before` and `after` as strings?

Comment: @@Iskuskov Alexander Yes

Comment: I think you can do the following steps: 1. use `id` from mesage key using `record_key` property of JDBC Sink Connector; 2. Use Cast SMT for `after` and `before` fields; 3. Use Replace SMT to rename ts_ms; 4. Use Replace SMT to filter fields

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DTO (Java object for your json payload which you are getting from your kafka topic) make use of this online converters helps you to convert your json to Java objects. [http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/][1]

Once you receive your message from your kafka topic, you can use objectmapper to convert that json and map it into your appropriate DTO objects.Once you have the object ready. You can make use of that object to extract the fields you want by just calling getId(),getBefore() etc..,

Here is some reference code which helps you understand:

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "test")
        public void listen(String payload)  {

            logger.info("Message Received from Kafka topic: {}", payload);

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

            DTOObject dtoObject = objectMapper.readValue(payload,DTOObject.class);

                logger.info("After Convertion: {}", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dtoObject));

                logger.info("Get Before:{}", dtoObject.getId());



        }
```

Comment: is this and SMT or what, as i mentioned i am using jdbc sink connector for target db, how can i make use this code snippet that you mentioned and where ? thanks